# Require at least one implementation?

Tags: java, osgi

How can i require at least one implementation of an certain api interface in osgi?

I for example have an @Component YellowBlock which uses another component (Map in this case):

```
@Component
public class YellowBlock implements BlockProvider {
@Reference
public void setMap(Map map){
```

This component never "goes live" (can't be seen by a ServiceTracker) in my osgi container when there is no other component that implements the Map interface. For example this one:

```
@Component
public class MapImpl implements Map{
```

If i add this one manually to the container the YellowBlock component "goes live".

[edit] My cardinality seems to be right: cardinality="1..1". I also found some talk about a timeout on the @reference annotation, but can't find much on that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question answers itself.

You asked "how can I require at least one implementation of a certain API interface", and then your example code does exactly that.

Comment: Cheers Neil, I was expecting an dependency error or similar error, because now a external user can "forget" to include the Map implementation in the osgi container and the entire thing would seem to run, but in fact it isn't running because an requirement is missing. The external user doesn't know that this is the case because no error was produced. Is it possible to notify the user of an missing requirement? Cause now it silently fails leaving the user wondering what is going on and no way to know how to solve it. In addition such @reference requirement doesn't seem to get resolved.

Comment: The thing is, in a running OSGi system it's quite normal for several components to be inactive. They may be waiting for services that come along later, or have just temporarily gone away. Or they may not have been configured to run. So, an inactive component is not an application level error unless you make it one. You could do this by having another component that depends on `YellowBlock` (perhaps with an optional-dynamic reference) and reports an error if `YellowBlock` does not appear when expected.

Comment: Thanks @Neil , so it is by design, thumbs up for the offered solutions, will take a peek if i will follow design or implement one of the solutions.